# How can I tell pest.rs to flatten grammar?

Tags: parsing, rust, pest

Let's say I have a rule like,

```
key = { ASCII_ALPHA ~ ( ASCII_ALPHA | "_" )+ }
value = { (!NEWLINE ~ ANY)+ }
keyvalue = { key ~ "=" ~ value?  }
option = { key }
```

This supports a

```
K=V
K=
K
```

Which is want to set/unset a `key`, and to specify an `option`, what I don't like is the syntax for `option` which produces an AST like this,

```
rule: option,
span: Span {
    str: "check_local_user",
    start: 302,
    end: 318,
},
inner: [
    Pair {
        rule: key,
        span: Span {
            str: "check_local_user",
            start: 302,
            end: 318,
        },
        inner: [],
    },
],
```

I don't like that my `option` has inner with `key`. I'm just wanting to the `option` to have the same grammar as a `key`. Is there any method in Pest.rs to write the grammar such that

```
inner { myStuff }
outer = { inner }
```

gets flattened to

```
outer = { myStuff }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the [Atomic Parsing Token `@`](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#atomic), I could accomplish this.

```
option = @{ key }
```

It's documented as,

> Any rules called by atomic rules **do not generate token pairs.**